# Why can't Jedi tell who can be mind tricked?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, the-force

From the movies:

- Qui-Gon fails (multiple times) at manipulating Watto on Tatooine in EpI
- Luke tried using it on Jabba in EpVI, to no avail

From elsewhere:

- Mace Windu failed to manipulate a Dagoyan to allow him access to the Queen's chambers on Bardotta
- Ahsoka Tano tries to get info on a potential hostage from a Mandalorian Security Officer, but fails

That makes at least four species that are resistant or immune to the Force Mind Trick, and there's probably many more. So my question is: **Why don't the Jedi know who's receptive and who's not?** Is this never a subject during their training? Why can't they sense when a creature isn't weak-minded enough to use this ability on?

Why isn't it as easy as:

```
if(target->IsWeakMinded())
{
    jediAbility.UseForceMindTrick(target) 
}
else
{
    jediAbility.CheatSomeOtherWay(target)
}
```

A follow up question would be whether or not Dark Jedi or Sith have this problem, as I've only found Light Side examples.

Legends answers are acceptable.

Comment: On the flip side, why should they be able to tell? In general it isn't easy to tell someones ability in some field without actually putting it to the test, why would fictional abilities be any different?

Comment: Keep in mind that Force users are not necessarily able to know everything in other scenarios as well.  Remember the scene from ESB, where Luke inquires about the fate of Han and Leia and Yoda is unable to answer?

Comment: Because they are very powerful fictional characters. They can sense lots of other things, including things that only give them "bad feelings" or "disturbances", from several miles away or lightyears away. Old Ben could tell when Alderaan got destroyed, so why could they not sense who even *might* be a possible victim of the mind trick?

Comment: And if they are totally unable to sense it, why is it not taught in the Academy? Surely that giant library has *some* notes on the subject.

Comment: Jedi can't do that, because PHP is of the Dark Side.

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd Old Ben could tell that many, many people died at once as he said he felt "as if millions of voices cried out in terror, and then suddenly silenced". Also, not all Jedi are permitted access to some of the Archives. And the giant library is called the Jedi Archives.

Answer (score 14):

Well, because method `isWeakMinded` is actually implemented like this :P

```
public boolean isWeakMinded(Target target, JediAbility jediAbility) {
    try {
        jediAbility.useForceMindTrick(target);
    } catch (NotWeakMindedException e) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

It goes without saying that all Jedi abilities are actually encoded in Java, and that is how the order actually got its name ;)

Comment: Excellent point.  This brings to mind the famous "these are not the droids you're looking for" scene in *A New Hope.*  Even if it were possible for Obi-Wan to determine ahead of time whether his mind trick would work, there wasn't time to "research" it—if he didn't take **_immediate_** action, it was likely that the whole party would have been arrested.

Comment: You code like the Dark Side. No *legitimate* Jedi would ever leave their brackets like that.

Comment: @SonOfSam My mentor taught me everything about the Force, even the nature of the Dark Side. :P

Comment: But didn't Yoda say 'There is no "try, only 'do'"'....?

Comment: @Pᴇᴛᴇ, yes, but clearly Yoda wasn't a competent coder because      do{jediAbility.useForceMindTrick(target);} while (!target.isTricked());    hangs your movie.

Comment: @rs.29 Was your mentor's name Sheev?

Comment: @ThePopMachine Unless George thought to put the Jedi code on a different thread

Comment: @SonOfSam, well, seeing as there's no apparent synchronization mechanism here, it would mean that targets change their mind with no tight relationship to when they the mind-trick is cast.   "These aren't the droids you're looking for. These aren't the droids you're looking for. These aren't the droids you're looking for. These aren't the droids you're looking for."  "Shut up, what's your problem?  Why do you keep saying th -- oh yeah, they aren't the droids we're looking for."

Comment: @Pᴇᴛᴇ Yoda was early proponent of Exception driven development. Once he got this shady Kamino library. He immediately took CloneArmy object from it, and used goToWar method. He got this huge Order66Exception, which almost crashed his JediOrder app in production .

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd - Of course no Jedi would write code like that.  Jedi are very careful with their parentheses.  Jedi are [lisp programmers](https://xkcd.com/297/).