# Why is Darth Maul "it"?

Tags: star-wars, names, the-phantom-menace, darth-maul

In *The Phantom Menace*, after Qui-Gon encounters Darth Maul for the first time, he escapes to Padmé's ship.    (Time of interest starting at 2:00)

> ANAKIN :  Are you alright?
>
> QUI-GON : I think so.
>
> OBI-WAN : What was **it**?
>
> QUI-GON : I'm not sure.   But **it** was well-trained in the Jedi arts.  [R2-D2 beeps]  My guess is, **it** was after the queen.
>
> ANAKIN : What are we going to do about **it**?
>
> QUI-GON : *(exhales)* We should be patient.  Anakin Skywalker, meet Obi-Wan Kenobi.
>
> ANAKIN : Hi.   You're a Jedi too?

Now, arguably the first and last instances of *it* may not refer to Darth Maul but the situation, but there are at least two undeniable instances in a row of Darth Maul being called **it**.

Now, this strikes me as strange because:

- (As far as I'm aware) there hasn't been another (non-droid) sentient referred to as **it**.
- Darth Maul clearly has masculine features
- Other aliens, far less humanoid and far less obviously gendered (from our point of view), are he or she.
- Even droids in the Star Wars universe have gender and some are called *he* or *she*.

In addition, according to a 1999 draft at [IMSDB](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-The-Phantom-Menace.html), it wasn't always this way:

> ANAKIN : Are you all right?
>
> QUI-GON : I think so... that was a surpirse I wont soon forget.
>
> OBI-WAN : What was it?
>
> QUI-GON : I don't know... but he was well trained in the Jedi arts. My
>   guess is he was after the Queen...
>
> ANAKIN : Do you think he'll follow us?
>
> QUI-GON : We'll be safe enough once we're in hyperspace, but I have no
>   doubt he knows our destination.
>
> ANAKIN : What are we going to do about it?
>
> OBI-WAN gives ANAKIN a "who are you?" look. ANAKIN returns an innocent
>   stare.
>
> QUI-GON : We will be patient. Anakin Skywalker, meet Obi-Wan Kenobi.
>
> ANAKIN : Pleased to meet you. Wow! You're a Jedi too?

So,

## What are the in-universe and out-of-universe stories behind the use of the genderless pronoun for Darth Maul?

Is it how Sith were referenced (despite other evidence)?   Was Darth Maul's species supposed to be known to Qui-Gon, and genderless?   Did Darth Maul have a Tumblr page where he (uh, it) professed its preferred pronouns?  Were decisions made at shoot-time, possibly because of the bookending uses of *it* for the situation in general?

Comment: The encounter was probably just too fast for Qui-Gon to determine Maul's gender. So he used the appropriate pronouns to convey that. Zabrak have both genders with the usual array of secondary characteristics.

Comment: @DampeS8N, even assuming this were true,  it wouldn't justify using "it".

Comment: Typical elitist Jedi. Usually they dish out this kind of contempt only for the muggles... eh.. non-Jedi, calling their weapons (and by unspoken extension them) "uncivilized" and such. They knew they weren't dealing with a fellow Jedi here, and doubted the Sith could have returned (as even the council was sceptical), ergo: **It.**

Comment: I agree that this too weird to not have a real answer somewhere. I have confidence in Valorum's ability to find an answer. :)

Comment: Because it's one big intergalactic game of tag now, and Maul is **it**

Comment: Genderless pronoun (as much as they exist in English) would be that "who was that". The use of it would imply they had no idea what it was, a primary concern before dealing with gender

Comment: @Naib, your contention that *that* is genederless, but *it* isn't is puzzling.   But I do agree that the choice of *What was it?* versus the possible alternatives *What was that?*, *Who was it?*, and *Who was that?* does suggest something odd, like he didn't know what species it was, the gender, and/or even whether it was a sentient (vs. a droid, say).   But I'm having trouble constructing a scenario which would naturally lead to that choice of words.   Hence the question.

Comment: (Also, everyone, I'm saddened nobody liked my joke.   It made me chuckle.)

Comment: @ThePopMachine I put this forward as an alternative view. Had Obi recognized the species stating something like "who was that" would be valid. No gender needed (as I said English is odd... extremely few gender neutral pronouns).  How well known were Zabraks to Obi?

Comment: @Naib, okay, I don't want to assume too much about the gender and xeno-politics of the Star Wars galaxy,    but Darth Maul is so "obviously masculine" that I find it hard to believe that if Obi-Wan knew nothing about that species,  he wouldn't still assume "he".  And if he does know the Zabrak, he would know they have obviously differentiated genders.   It seems to me,  you only say *it* if you can't guess or you know the species isn't gendered.

Comment: Turns out, Darth Maul *also* takes the form of an evil clown that hides in sewers and lured children to their deaths.  It’s what he was doing all through episodes 2-8.

Answer (score 8):

Sadly as there is no further explanation on why Qui-Gon called Maul an it we can only take a guess. A very educated guess though.

We need to take into consideration that the fight lasted only mere moments and that the Star Wars universe contains A LOT of different species (even two legged ones). With some of the species looking very similar to each other and also some having 2 genders, some 1 and some probably more than 2.

As a Jedi, Qui-Gon travelled the galaxy a bit but has probably not seen every species, yet. Thus the information above combined with the shortness of the battle, it is very probable that Qui-Gon was unable to be completely sure what species Maul hailed from....and also what gender he had.

Thus calling Maul an it is the most neutral method of talking about Maul (I dare say even the Jedi way is that way......as it is the most even way of talking about Maul without implying something that the Jedi was not sure about).

Comment: [Why couldn't he sense what Maul's species was?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/150617/why-cant-jedi-tell-who-can-be-mind-tricked)

Comment: Darth Maul is a Zabrak, which is also the species of Jedi Master [Aegen Kolar](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Agen_Kolar). Granted, they have different skin tones (Maul is red, Kolar is brown) and the fight was brief, but you'd think that Qui-Gon would at least know a little bit about the species of each of the members of the Jedi Council!

Comment: @Thunderforge I'm not sure that he could tell a zabrak within mere moments though. We shouldn't forget that there are millions of species and MANY of them are very similar in appearance to each other. And with cybernetics and even shapechangers existing in that universe telling one others species by just a very short fight from ones live could be very hard. Even though he CAN be familiar with the species it is questionable if he saw enough to be sure that it is that species and not a different one.

Comment: It is possible that by referring to Maul as "It", Qui-Gon meant not "What species is it", but "what is it", more precisely "what Dark Side group does that guy belong to", or "am I right that it is a Sith"?